# How to display an image from database with <PagedList> in MVC 4 EF 6

Tags: c#, image, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This challenge is bugging me for days now. I am obviously doing something wrong, but I wish I knew what.

How can I display my pictures in my Index View when using a PagedList class?

I cannot get a picture to display properly, when using the PagedList Class. All works just fine in my *Edit View* when using `@model HeHu.Models.Candidate`, but when trying to show the pictures in my Index View that is using PagedList `@model PagedList.IPagedList<HeHu.Models.Candidate>`, the field  Model.PictFiles is not recognized as in the following code:

```
@if (Model.PictFiles.Any(.....)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img width="150" src="~/PictFile?id=@Model.PictFiles.First(.....)
    </div>
</div>
}
```

[Picture of red-underlined code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL0AB.png)

What I want to achieve:
Displaying records of candidates per row, including the picture.

The models are the following:

Candidate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HeHu.Models
{
    public class Candidate
    {        
        public int CandidateID { get; set; }
        public int CsearchID { get; set; }
        [StringLength (50)]
        public string CandLastName { get; set; 
        public string CandFirstName { get; set; }
        public string CandCompany { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        public virtual Csearch Csearch { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CandAction> CandAction { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PictFile> PictFiles { get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Pictfile:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace HeHu.Models
{
    public class PictFile
    {
        public int PictFileId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string PictFileName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
        public FileType FileType { get; set; }
        public int CandidateId { get; set; }
        public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Controller for the index is (simplified) as follows:

```
public class CandidateController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentfilter, string searchString, int? opdrachtNummer, int? id, int? page)
    {
        //Adding the Pager 
        if (searchString != null || opdrachtNummer.HasValue)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentfilter;
        }
        ViewBag.Currentfilter = searchString;

        var candidates = from c in db.Candidates
                         .Include(c => c.PictFiles)
                         .Include(c => c.FilePaths)
                         select c;


        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(candidates.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));         
    }
```

And the controller for the image:

```
using HeHu.DAL;
using HeHu.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HeHu.Controllers
{

    public class PictFileController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        // GET: PictFile
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var pictFileToRetrieve = db.PictFiles.Find(id);
            return File(pictFileToRetrieve.Content, pictFileToRetrieve.ContentType);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the View looks like this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<HeHu.Models.Candidate>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Candidates";
 }

<h2><cr/>Kandidaten</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Candidate", null, FormMethod.Get, new {       enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<table class="table">

<tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>            
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandLastName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandFirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandCompany)
        </td>           
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CandidateID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CandidateID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CandidateID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

}
<br />
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Answer (score 0):

In you Edit View it's normal it works the way you use the helper:

```
@if (Model.PictFiles.Any(.....)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img width="150" src="~/PictFile?id=@Model.PictFiles.First(.....)
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Model here refers to the Candidate type. However in your Index view you have a paged list of candidates, so in order to use the helper to show the picture for a given candidate, you should use the item in the collection you're iterating over:

Add a td to show the candidate's picture:

```
<td>
  @if (item.PictFiles.Any(x => x.FileType == FileType.PersonalPicture))
  {
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <img width="150" src="~/PictFile?id=@(item.PictFiles.First(x => x.FileType == FileType.PersonalPicture).PictFileId)"/>
      </div>
  }
</td>
```

Do note, however, that this time you can't ask for Model.PictFiles as Model is not a `Candidate` but a `PagedList` of them. Also, as you're iterating over the Model in a foreach loop, you can the use the foreach variable - item - for your purpose:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>  
        <td>
            @if (item.PictFiles.Any(x => x.FileType == FileType.PersonalPicture))
            {
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  <img width="150" src="~/PictFile?id=@(item.PictFiles.First(x => x.FileType == FileType.PersonalPicture).PictFileId)"/>
              </div>
            }
        </td>        
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandLastName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandFirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandCompany)
        </td>           
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CandidateID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CandidateID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CandidateID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karel for both the right explanation and the right answer! It works perfectly. The final page is generated as follows. What I find interesting is the `src="/PictFiles?id=1"`. It looks as if it stores the file in a directory and not in database.

```
<td>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img width="150" src="/PictFile?id=1" />
    </div>
 </td>
```